# Linear combination of anomalous dimensions in effective potential on pseudomoduli space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, renormalization, moduli

In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703281) of Intriligator, Seiberg, and Shih from 2007, they give an expression for the effective potential on the pseudo-moduli space $X$, estimated at large $X$ (equation 1.3).

In this equation, "$\gamma$ is the anomalous dimension of a particular linear combination of them". Later on in the paper they give examples for this (eq. 4.9).

What is the formula for this $\gamma$ and how do we reach this expression?

Comment: I suspect the derivation of the formula for the potential is in Witten's paper cited as 18, http://inspirehep.net/record/167850 - The "formula" for the anomalous dimension is whatever it always is. It appears in the exponent for the 2-point function of this operator, and the anomalous (non-classical) contribution itself may be determined from the coefficient of a log divergence in this 2-point function.